# How can I subdivide a shape and keep its shape?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, subdivision-surface

Is it possible that I can subdivide a shape in blender to add new faces, and keep its shape. More specifically it's a rectangle and when I subdivide it the shape changes.

This is before the subdivision:
[image]

This is after:
[image]

Comment: How did you subdivide it? Did you do this in Edit mode, with a modifier or by another mean?

Comment: How did you subdivide it? If you select All in Edit mode then right-click and choose 'Subdivide' there's no way the overall shape of a cube should change.

Comment: if you've right clicked > Subdivide, look into the Operator box (panel on the bottom left), make sure that the Smoothness value is at 0

Answer (score 13):

There are two options:

**1.** Instead of the default "*Catmull-Clark*", using the "*Simple*" mode of the [*Subdivision Surface*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html#subdivision-surface-modifier) modifier will retain the shape of your mesh. Since this is a modifier, you can change the parameters later down the line:

[image]

**2.** You can enter into *Edit Mode*, select the geometry you wish to subdivide, right click and select "*Subdivide*". You can change the parameters in the "*Adjust Last Operation*" menu in the bottom-left corner (shortcut: <kbd>F9</kbd>), but since this is an *Edit Mode* operation, the changes are permanent once you take another action.

[image]